# How to write a Typescript class definition for a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, typescript

I want to write a Typescript definition file (.d.ts) for this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

So here's what I've started with:

```
declare module Canvas {
    class Canvas {
        constructor(width: number, height: number);
    }
}

declare module "canvas" {
    export = Canvas;
}
```

This is working when I import & call the module like this:

```
/// <reference path="./canvas.d.ts" />
import * as Canvas from "canvas";
new Canvas.Canvas(32, 32)
```

However, I want to call the class like this:

```
new Canvas(32, 32)
```

I also want to add two things to the class:

- It should return an `HTMLCanvasElement` so It can work just like the normal  Canvas api
- I also want to add an .Image property to the module which is accessible without constructing the class.

Here's an example of what I'm waiting for:

```
import * as Canvas from "canvas";
var Image  = Canvas.Image;
var canvas = new Canvas(32, 32);
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage and every regular functions...
[...]
```

I also want to add an optional callback parameter to `canvas.toDataURL()`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for instantiating the class without having to specify the module name every time you use new:

```
/// <reference path="./canvas.d.ts" />
import Canvas1 = Canvas.Canvas;

var canvas = new Canvas1(32, 32);
```